# extract database name from a wp-config.php file

Tags: wordpress, bash, ssh, command-line-interface

Hello I'm trying to run my ssh bash script from root (which has access to all hundreds of databases on my server).  I'm trying to get the database name of my wordpress websites without having to login and open the file and copy and paste the db name.  I'm doing this so I can then continue on to do other things in the particular database using the scripts.

So the line item for the database in file wp-config.php looks like this always: name define( 'DB_NAME', 'xyz' );

I'm simply trying to find that line item and then get/extract and use that db name (ie. xyz) later in the script (ie. $db).  That's it.

I'm assuming using grep/sed/regex or combo or something would do it but I can't find out how.  Let me know if anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a suitable task for sed. Selecting the matching define line using a regexp and extract the value using a capture group:

```
db=$(sed -n "s/define( *'DB_NAME', *'\([^']*\)'.*/\1/p" wp-config.php)
echo $db
```

Comment: Ok great thanks for the response! What variable would i use to pass the value on? ie if I used $db or something. How would I call that back up on the next line of the script?

Comment: You need shell command substitution to store the result. I have added the coded to the answer

Answer (score 0):

This code is worked for me i have extrected the database details from wp-config.php and past it to myfile.php

```
//Path to your wp-config.php file
$wp_config_path = 'wp-config.php';
// Include the wp-config.php file
if (file_exists($wp_config_path)) {
    include($wp_config_path);
    // Retrieve the database credentials
    $db_name = defined('DB_NAME') ? DB_NAME : '';
    $db_user = defined('DB_USER') ? DB_USER : '';
    $db_password = defined('DB_PASSWORD') ? DB_PASSWORD : '';
    $db_host = defined('DB_HOST') ? DB_HOST : '';
} else {
    echo "wp-config.php not found or invalid path.";
}
```

Note:Make sure your path is correct, or your file and the wp-config is in the same folder..